# Unable to store images to database

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4

The following code below:

```
 [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(Car model, HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        var currentUser = UserManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
        var user = this.db.Users.Where(u => u.Id == currentUser.Id).FirstOrDefault();

        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                var photo = new FilePath
                {
                    FileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + System.IO.Path.GetExtension(file.FileName),
                    FileType = FileType.Photo
                };
                model.FilePaths = new List<FilePath>();
                model.FilePaths.Add(photo);
                file.SaveAs(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Images/"), photo.FileName));

            }
            user.Cars.Add(model);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Default", "Home");
        }

        SetCategoryViewBag(model.Category.CategoryId);

        return View(model);
       }
```

Won't let me to store any images to the database. The image table doesn't store any information at all. However, the cars table is ok, but images is still showing as null.

What have I done wrong here?

Edit:

Car model:

```
    public class Car
{
    [Key]
    public int CarId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<FilePath> FilePaths { get; set; }

}
```

FilePath model:

```
  public class FilePath
{
    public int FilePathId { get; set; }
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public FileType FileType { get; set; }

    public int CarId { get; set; }

   public virtual Car Cars { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Your code does not save the file to a database. Its saving to to a file system (in the `/Images` directory) Are you wanting to save the path of the file in the `Cars` table?

Comment: That's right. I want to save the path of the file in the Cars table..

Comment: Its not clear what `FilePath` is or why you creating a collection of `FilePath` (do you have multiple files associated with each `Car`?). Assuming only one file per `Car`, your table/model should contain a property (say) `string Path` and then `model.Path = yourPath;`.

Comment: For FilePath I have used this tutorial link: http://bit.ly/1gWXyqp. Well, I have linked the FilePath as a referance to Car model like this public virtual ICollection<FilePath> FilePaths { get; set; } and in FilePath model i also have referred the Car like public int CarId { get; set; } public virtual Car Cars { get; set; }. I hope this was understandable

Comment: Please see above for models.

Comment: The only reason to do that would be to associate multiple files with each `Car` object. In which case you need to add each file to the context separately e.g. - `foreach(FilePath path in model.FilePaths) { db.FilePaths.Add(path) }` then call `db.SaveChanges();`

Comment: But there is no reason to add the `FilePaths` to the model collection and since in this case you only have one file it can just be `db.FilePaths.Add(photo)`. You will also need to set the `CarId` of `FilePath` before you save it (and if your creating a new `Car`, you will need to add and save that first so that you can get its `CarId` property.

Comment: Thanks Stephen! Finally it works now.